# How to make a list of the summed digits, in another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to easily convert numbers in a list into single digits for example

```
population = ['10001','11111','11010','110001']

into ['1','0','0','0','1'] 

add each digit in each set and put it in another list like 
this

evaluation = [2,5,3,3] (adding up all the 1's up on the first list)
```

I'm very new to Python so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly

Comment: `print(list(item.count('1') for item in population))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is iterate over the `population` list and use [str.count('character')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count the `'1'`'s in each "number" string:

```
evaluation = list(item.count('1') for item in population)
```

`evaluation` will contain the desired counts:

```
>>> print(evaluation)
[2, 5, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only dealing with zeros and ones, then @davedwards is a good solution.  Count the instances of `'1'` in each string.

```
out = [x.count('1') for x in population]
```

If you need the solution to be more extensible to values other than 0 and 1, you can convert each digit to an int and sum the integers.

```
out = [sum(map(int, x)) for x in population]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> population = ['10001','11111','11010','110001']
>>> [Counter(x).get('1', 0) for x in population]
[2, 5, 3, 3]
```

A functional aproach would be to also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(map(itemgetter('1'), map(Counter, population)))
[2, 5, 3, 3]
```